# How to create aliases for a DB2 column in a java string query?

Tags: java, sql, db2

Here is my query , In DB Visualizer it works fine :

```
String query ="SELECT  emp_id AS Class_ID \n" +
                "       ,emp_name as Name \n" +
                "       ,emp_salary as Salary\n" +
                "FROM   Employee\n"
```

In java , it gives this error :

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10150][10300][4.26.14] Invalid parameter: Unknown column name Class_ID. ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null
```

Comment: I have rem oved those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Show the exact line of your java code throwing this error.

Comment: Its coming on first line of the query itself :  Invalid parameter: Unknown column name Class_ID

Comment: This is not an answer to my request.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need double quotes to delimit alias.  So just use:

```
String query ="SELECT ID AS Class_ID FROM Employee";
```

Comment: That is not working..I have multiple fields.. Here is my query :

Comment: @aka_GK . . . remove the `\n`s from the query string.